# Using SSL certificate files outside container on Jelastic

Tags: ssl, nginx, jelastic

My server configuration on Jelastic are one Container with Nginx and another with Node, i don´t have ftp access to the Nginx container only the Node one. 
I´m trying to use multiple domains with multiple ssl certificates just like I already did with Apache/PHP.
But I searched and have no idea of how to make Nginx search for ssl files outside his container.

Comment: What is an SSL certificated file?

Comment: The .crt and .key files created when signing SSL. like here: [http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html](http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html)

Comment: Do you mean *certificate* files?

Comment: Iep, sorry my typo (edited).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to setup multiple SSL on the one **NGINX** container, but it could be done directly in **NGINX** configurations only. We would like to recommend you to use our feature - [Direct Access to the container](https://docs.jelastic.com/ssh-access#direct-access). This feature provides the **root** access inside the container of the environment via **SSH** connection and will help you to make necessary configurations in an easy way.

After the configuring of **NGINX**, you can apply the changes without downtime using the command: `sudo service nginx reload` instead of `sudo service nginx restart`.

It should be noted that because there is 1 IP in the container, multiple **SSL** certificates can be served via **SNI** only. You can read more about **SNI** in the next [article](http://blog.layershift.com/sni-ssl-production-ready/).

We would like to emphasize, that at the moment **SNI** is supported by **all modern OS** and **browsers** and can be used without any inconveniences, except old mobile OS and versions of **IE <7** on the **MS Windows XP**.

Also, as an alternative, you can use **SAN** certificate, that supports the multiple domains as well, and in this case, the certificate can be added to the **NGINX** node by Jelastic's [BindSSL](https://docs.jelastic.com/api/?class=environment.Binder&member=BindSSL) API method.